# People Picker not showing user results if we not entered exact

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

We have enabled Claims authentication with LDAP membership role. Its working fine. In people picker if we enter the exact user name then only search results showing Form Auth user. otherwise not showing the users. showing error "No results were found to match your search item. Please enter a new term or less specific term."

Can you please any one help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the question correctly, you will need to modify webconfig section `<PeoplePickerWildcards>` (to be precisier, `configuration/SharePoint/PeoplePickerWildcards`) to achieve this, as it described in following MSDN article:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb975136.aspx

The sample code:

```
<PeoplePickerWildcards>
  <clear />
  <add key="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" value="%" />
  <add key="fbaMembers" value="%" />
</PeoplePickerWildcards>
```

Also I'd recommend you to read an essential, "must-read" article on configuring People Picker by using stsadm:

- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg602075.aspx

, particularly, about the [Peoplepicker-searchadcustomquery](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262988.aspx) property.

Comment: Thanks Omlin...

I tried with only adding <add key="fbaMembers" value="%" />
this in my web.config CA & my WA, is not working. 

let me ceck the links and update you.

Comment: `key` attribute may be different for you - that depends from actual provider name. So yes, you should check the links :) Anyway, they provide huge amount of very useful information! :) And have a look at this blog post also: http://sharepointyankee.com/2010/12/30/wildcard-search-for-forms-based-authentication-users-in-the-sharepoint-2010-people-picker-not-working/

Comment: I was tried with my own attribute key value only, after reading that blog post yesterday. let me go through that links and check.

Answer (score 0):

For LDAP membership providers, use

```
<add key="fbaMembers" value="*" />
```